# Reuse Table View variables Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

Here is the table view:

```
   public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var rowData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
           let too: AnyObject = rowData ["time"] as NSString
        var name: String = rowData["time"] as String
        var formattedPrice: String = rowData["date"] as String

        var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = name
        alert.message = formattedPrice
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
         println ("hi")
         println (too)   
    }
```

I need to reference these variables in another view controller. I have not been able to fit that statement above in this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;
svc.toPass = textField.text
}
}
```

I am trying to segue off cell click. 
    from http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "fit that statement above in this". If your segue is connected to a cell, then the sender argument (in prepareForSegue:sender) will be the cell, and you can use the table view method, indexPathForCell: to get the indexPath. You don't need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all.

Comment: How do connect a segue to a cell click?

Comment: Right click (or control click) on the cell, and drag to the controller (the same as you do for any segue).

Comment: Is it possible to recognize a sharedinstance value defined in one class, in another class, or view controller?

Comment: I don't know what you men by "shared instance value". In any case, you can't make IBOutlet connections between controllers.

Comment: Are you telling me I can not take the value of what was displayed in a table view cell through  cell.textLabel!.text can not be passed into another view controller label or text field?

Comment: println (too) outputs when cell is clicked value of let too: AnyObject = rowData ["time"] as NSString ..... how can I get that same value in the next view controller that appears?

Comment: No, that's not what I was saying. You can do that, and there are hundreds of answers on SO about passing data between controllers, so you should do some searching.

Comment: I have only found two, singletons, and prepare for segues. But I am not able to combine a prepare for segue with the tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {}

Comment: This search, "[ios] pass data between view controllers" turned up 667 results. Also, as I told you in my first comment, you shouldn't implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all in this situation, only prepareForSegue.

Comment: I need didSelectRowAtIndexPath to push segue and set off alert, and run an NSDictionary.

Comment: How can prepareforsegue recognize what cell was clicked without referencing the viewtable?

Comment: You can do all of the same code in prepareForSegue. As I said, the sender will be the cell, so you can use NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender]; Once you have the indexPath, you can access your model with it to get any data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it isn't a lot of data, the strategy I use to pass data between view controllers is to store the value in `NSUserDefaults`.

**Setting A Value**: When you first get the data, store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() //This class variable needs to be defined every class where you set or fetch values from NSUserDefaults
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var rowData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    let too: AnyObject = rowData ["time"] as NSString
    var name: String = rowData["time"] as String
    var formattedPrice: String = rowData["date"] as String
    defaults.setObject(rowData, forKey: "rowData")
    defaults.setObject(too, forKey: "too")
    defaults.setObject(name, forKey: "name")
    defaults.setObject(formattedPrice, forKey: "formattedPrice")
    defaults.synchronize() //Call this after you're done editing defaults, it saves your change to the disk

    var alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = name
    alert.message = formattedPrice
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
    alert.show()
     println ("hi")
     println (too)   
}
```

**Fetching A Value**: When you need to get the values, just grab it from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.dictionaryForKey("rowData") as? NSDictionary
defaults.objectForKey("too") as? String
defaults.objectForKey("name") as? String
defaults.objectForKey("formattedPrice") as? String
```

Doing that gives you access to the stored values in any class and allows the data to persist after the app is closed and reopened. If you want to clear the data after the app closes, in AppDelegate `applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)` function, call the [removeObjectForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/removeObjectForKey:) function for each key previously set.

```
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.removeObjectForKey("rowData")
defaults.removeObjectForKey("too")
defaults.removeObjectForKey("name")
defaults.removeObjectForKey("formattedPrice")
defaults.synchronize()
```

**Helpful Source on NSUserDefaults**:

`NSUserDefulats` Class Reference: Link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

Comment: Sure thing! Please up-vote the answer too if you thought it was good.

Comment: I tried up voting you, I don't have 15 creds so I can't upgrade. If you think my question was good, please up vote it!

Comment: I forgot to add this: The final statement you should make after editing the defaults in a method is the `defaults.synchronize()` function. That will save all your change to the disk.